# "Openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS Error" while running php composer.phar install in cakephp

Tags: docker, ssl, cakephp, openssl, tls1.2

I am setting up Cakephp project in my local system. I have git cloned the project inside the **htdocs** folder of Xaamp. When I run "**php composer.phar install**" it gives me this error
"The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl ext
ension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true."
I have used Xaamp as Apache Server.
I have also uncommented **extension=openssl** in the php.ini file at both Xaamp Directory and php installed directory.

Also, Iam having another error as below

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: bz2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: fileinfo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: gettext: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: gettext: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: exif: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: exif: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0    
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified procedure could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ftp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: ftp: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20220829
PHP    compiled with module API=20210902
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Please give an suggestions and ideas to fix and run the project.

I have uncommented **extension=openssl** in the php.ini file at both Xaamp Directory and php installed directory.
I also tried disabling tls , but that didn't solve the problem.
Looked through the most of the stackoverflow solution but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you have extensions that were installed from some source that doesn't match the rest of your PHP installation.

Comment: Hello @GregSchmidt. Can you please explain it a bit I am new to php in general.

Comment: PHP is composed of a core executable and a bunch of extensions that get loaded on demand. The versions of the extensions must be compatible with the version of the core executable. Your error messages are reporting different version numbers. I can't tell you why that's happening, it'll be something non-standard about how you installed PHP on your system. Maybe you downloaded an extension from somewhere without realizing what version it was? Maybe you upgraded one piece without upgrading it all?